# How to return the result of only the first of two concurrent async suspend functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

There is the following example in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html)

```
suspend fun concurrentSum(): Int = coroutineScope {
    val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
    val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
    one.await() + two.await()
}
```

How do I change the above so that only the value of the first completed function is returned?

```
suspend fun fasterUseful(): Int = coroutineScope {
        val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
        val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
        // ????? one.await() || two.await() whichever faster
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select<Int> {
    one.onAwait { it }
    two.onAwait { it }
}
```

See [select expresions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html#selecting-deferred-values). `selectUnbiased` if you don't want to give the first clause priority.